# Issue on deploying Azure Container Instance via YAML with Tenant Reuse

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have facing issue on deployment of ACI via YAML,

Followed the document on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-reference-yaml

To Reuse Scope with Tenant.

But unable to provision getting error as

[image]

[image]

```yaml
apiVersion: '2021-10-01'
location: centralindia
name: helloworldcontainer
properties:
  containers:
  - name: helloworld
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld
      ports:
      - port: 80
        protocol: TCP
  osType: Linux
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '80'
    dnsNameLabelReusePolicy: Default
tags: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the tenant scope resuse, add the    `dnsNameLabel`  and `autoGeneratedDomainNameLabelScope` properties under the `ipAddress` to the ACI deployment file.
The complete aci yaml code looks like below.

```
apiVersion: '2021-10-01'
location: australiaeast
name: helloworldcontainer03
properties:
  containers:
  - name: helloworld03
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld
      ports:
      - port: 80
        protocol: TCP
      resources: 
        requests:
          memoryInGB: 1.5
          cpu: 1
        limits:
          memoryInGB: 1.5
          cpu: 1
  osType: Linux
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '80'
    dnsNameLabel: helloworldcontainer03dns
    autoGeneratedDomainNameLabelScope: TenantReuse
tags: {}
```

Next, apply the below command to deploy ACI.

```
az container create --resource-group <resource-group-name> --file aci-deploy.yaml
```

Verify the deployment using the below command.

```
az container show --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name helloworldcontainer03 --output table
```

[image]